# find out latex font used in a pdf

Tags: fonts, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Given a pdf created using latex, is it possible to find out the font used?There is maybe a package or method to find what is the type of font?Thanks to everyone

Comment: Look at the file properties. It should list the names of the fonts used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your PDF reader of choice, find the "File Properties" option. This should list various facts about the file, including which fonts are used. If that doesn't work, there are various internet forums where you can ask people to identify a font.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a simple solution that is portable between different platform, you can install the [xpdf bundle](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html). It comes with the `pdffonts` command line tool that allows to know the fonts used in a whole PDF, or a smallest part of it (e.g. a page). Usage example:

```
pdffonts.exe -f 3 -l 3 c:\path\to\some\myfile.pdf
```

This will show you the fonts used in the third page of the `myfile.pdf` file